Visual Studio 2022 (v.17.11.1) loses all references after a new C# script is added in Unity 2022.3.17f
How to fix the issue, that Visual Studio 2022 (v.17.11.1) loses all references after a new C# script is added in unity (2022.3.17f)? The issue is appeared after I made a Visual Studio update to the version 17.11.1 two days ago.
If I create a new script in unity editor and then open it in Visual Studio 2022, all the references in the project are marked with yellow triangle.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I should always close the Visual Studio and reopen it, so that the  error * CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) disappears.
I have tried:

Unity > Edit > Preferences > External Tools > "Regenerate project files"
Rebuild Solution
Delete .vs & obj folders & rebuild solution
Unity Editor > Right button click > Reimport All
Reinstall Unity & Visual Studio

Nothing works, except when I close & reopen VS2022.
I've also noticed, that Intellisense doesn't work also.
Any ideas?

I'm not using VS for many years because of its huge size and tons of errors. I recommend two things: 1. Post this issue on VS support forums, 2. Move to VS Code editor, as it is much more lightweight, has good support and tons of plugins for Unity.
